SQLAlchemy - Defining sequences with ORM
An example of how to define a column with core could be:
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

A similar way to define the same column with orm in SQLAlchemy 2.0 is:
id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

But what if we need to define a sequence name? With core we do:
id = Column(Integer, Sequence('sequence_name'), primary_key=True)

How can we define sequence names with orm in SQLAlchemy 2.0?
Seems that a 'sequence' attribute doesn`t exits in mapped_column.
Does anyone knows how to do it or how to find it in the docs?

From my experience, you typically integrate Core's Sequence functionality into the ORM model definition, allowing you to specify a custom sequence name for primary keys or other auto-incrementing fields.
It would look something like this:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'
    
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('sequence_name'), primary_key=True)


I think maybe they meant the new mapped_column version.  It looks pretty similar, maybe you could include it alongside the traditional Column version?

Yes, I meant the new mapped_colun version. How can we define a sequence name using mapped column? Something like this id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, Sequece('sequence_name'), doesn`t seems to work.
